# What is the best way to add temporary information to a Django model? (without creating a new model)

Tags: python, django, django-models

The best way to understand my question is through code:

```
class ToDoList(TimeStampedModel):
    DEFAULT_THEME = 1

    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    ... # other fields
    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        ('C', 'CREATED'),
        ('R', 'READY'),
        ('V', 'VALIDATED')
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default='C')
```

There are several types of users

- Creators: who can create a ToDoList and request a validation
- Validators: who can validate the list

Now, when a Validator rejects a validation request, he must also provide a reason. This will probably happen in no more than 10% of all cases, so I don't want to add a *rejection_reason* field on my ToDoList model.

I know one obvious solution is to create another model, called Reason, with just one char field and a FK to my ToDo model, but I would like to know if there is any better way to do this.

I don't know if this helps, but I'm using django-rest-framework for the API.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

After a validator rejects the List, he must provide the reason so that the Creator can change whatever is wrong with the List. After making the changes, the Creator requests again a validation. The cycle continues until the Validator accepts the ToDoList. At this moment, the rejection reason is no longer needed, so it can be deleted.

So, in the end, the rejection reason will no longer exist and I don't think it is ok (from a db space point of view) to have a field that will only be used temporary.

Comment: Since rejection is specifically related to your model it should belong to the model, and since that field is going to be filled in random times I see no reason not to move the field within the model.
If you need it appearing on certain circumstances, you can do that with some common methods, one would be to make the field hidden, if the field needs to be filled then with some js make it visible and allow the user to fill the reason. Another way would be with a dummy field which after form validation generates the content of the field.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my concern is not for how I can hide/show the field, but rather for database space. Also, I forgot to mention that once a ToDoList becomes validated, the rejection reason doesn't matter anymore (it will be deleted). So I don't think it's worth to have a 1000 characters field which will be used so rarely...

Comment: You want to use the rejection for something as an email? provide that information (not to confuse people answering) in your question, if yes then yes you certainly don't need it, use only a Form Field, manipulate the data after form validation and at the end of the request it's gone.

Comment: I have updated my question :) hope it's clear now.

Comment: With the update, I don't see a way avoiding the db (since from your description I understand that this gets stored until the creator re-requests validation, something that you can't predict when it's going to happen), but then again how many records and how much traffic are we talking about that this would oppose a problem to your flow?
After all you can delete the reason entry after the finalization of the process.

Comment: You're right, it's probably not worth the bother  to try and do anything complicated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're worrying unnecessarily about storing a (presumably) small amount of text along with your `ToDoList`. Here's how I would handle it, if the goal was to keep it simple, and not add another model.

```
class ToDoList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    validated_at = models.DateTimeField(..., null=True, editable=False)
    rejection_reason = models.TextFiel(..., editable=False)
```

Query for `validated_at__isnull=False` to get validated todo lists, ignoring `rejection_reason` altogether. Query for `validated_at__isnull=True` to get a list of unvalidated todo lists, and use `rejection_reason` to display the reason to the user. If you want to save space in your database, empty the `rejection_reason` field when a todo list is validated. You can also use `filter (rejection_reason="")` to narrow the todo lists to those that don't have a rejection reason (e.g., those that haven't been validated or rejected yet), or `exclude` on the same thing to get those that have been rejected.

Comment: Yup, this is probably the way I'll do it. Why do you suggest TextField instead of CharField?

Comment: @AdelaN `TextField` because you don't need to worry about length limits, but a `CharField` might be better, especially if you want to predict the maximum size of your database.

Comment: @AdelaN also see the extra bit I added to the bottom of my answer.